# Add multiple components to child component via slot

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-slot

I have a pretty simple implementation so I feel like this may be a silly question. Just starting with vue I am trying to make a component be able to list other components; kind of like a reusable List, Table, Grid, ect.

Parent component imports `gridView` as a normal component:

```
<template>
  <div :id="id" class="grid-view">
    <slot></slot>
  </div>
</template>
```

And then in another component I attempt to build this:

```
<grid-view :dataSource="items">
  <grid-view-item-test
    v-for="(item, index) in items"
    :key="index"
    :title="item.title"
  />
</grid-view>
```

And then `grid-view-item-test` is simple. `title` being a prop. Works completely fine standing alone or without the use of a slot, but I wanted to make `grid-view` reusable to just take whatever other component I add and display as-is.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div>{{ title }}</div>
  </div>
</template>
```

If I were to do something like this:

```
<grid-view :dataSource="items">
   <grid-view-item-test
     :key="index"
     :title="'Test 1'"
   />
   <grid-view-item-test
     :title="'Test 2'"
   />
   <grid-view-item-test
     :title="'Test 3'"
   />
</grid-view>
```

It works completely fine. Am I doing the loop wrong? I can confirm the loop works to get the number of items correctly. If I make a default fallback on the slot - I get the correct number, and I have printed it directly outside of the `grid-view` component.

Is this not a possibility? If not, would you just use HTML instead of a component for a reusable table as that seems to work fine.

Edit:

It works completely fine if I use an of strings, or numbers, but not objects.

I've tracked it down to `items` being an empty array as a computed variable and then throwing `TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'oldChildren[i]')`. Can confirm that `items` begins empty, and then is populated once a database call sets it, but I'm guess I'm not able to do something like that with slots?

After more testing it fails when you update the dataSet (`items`) at all. Is re-rending not possible with slots like this?

It works flawlessly if I have an empty div (or anything) when there are no items in the initial array.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question. What's the issue with this?

Comment: @Daniel_Knights Added some more information under Edits as I continue to debug. Looks like it may be a limitation of Vue slots or a limitation of my understanding.

Answer (score 1):

You probably should provide more a more accurate code because I don't see any problem with what you provided

Working example:

```js
const gridView = Vue.component('gridView', {
  props: ['dataSource'],
  template: `
    <div class="grid-view">
      <h4>My grid</h4>
      <slot></slot>
    </div>
  `
})

const gridItem = Vue.component('grid-view-item-test', {
  props: ['title'],
  template: `
    <div>
      <div>{{ title }}</div>
    </div>
  `
})

const vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    items: [{
        title: 'Test 1'
      },
      {
        title: 'Test 2'
      },
      {
        title: 'Test 3'
      },
    ]
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <grid-view :data-source="items">
    <grid-view-item-test v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index" :title="item.title" />
  </grid-view>
</div>
```

Comment: After further investigation it seems to be caused by the data being a computed variable and coming from an async call to the database - `item` starts off as an empty array and then is populated. I am assuming Vue doesn't like having 0 items in the array and then updating it?

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with slots. If your `computed` is throwing an error after data was fetched from the server, then your array is still empty - nothing can render. The problem is in that computed prop (your code) ...not Vue

Comment: Computed property has data after its fetched. The issue is, if there's no data, it gives that error. So, I solved it by adding a random DIV if the array is empty, but I feel like there should be a different approach to that. Seems hacky. (btw Vue is throwing an error - computed property is equal to the correct data after a few seconds (but after mounted)).

Comment: There is another approach. Fix your `computed` to work correctly is there is no data. That's it

Comment: What should it do? it already returns an empty array initially? I think the issue is `grid-view` does not have any content in it with the slot?